# not getting registered gcm (google cloud messaging)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to register with GCM by

```
GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
```

App is not crashing but, I am not getting registered. This is the logcat output:

```
D/GCMRegistrar﹕ resetting backoff for com.example.android.mtesapp
V/GCMRegistrar﹕ Registering app com.example.android.mtesapp of senders 22070897234234
V/a﹕ START
V/GCMBroadcastReceiver﹕ onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
V/GCMBroadcastReceiver﹕ GCM IntentService class: com.example.android.mtesapp.GCMIntentService
V/GCMBaseIntentService﹕ Acquiring wakelock
D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 30(0x6d74657366726f),sn(),family 0,flags 4
D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo-,err=8
D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 30(0x6d74657366726f),sn(),family 0,flags 1024
D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo-, 1
D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy+
```

I don't know what is that `err=8`?
Please help me with this.. thanks..

Comment: it looks like everything is working fine - you're receiving `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION` - what makes you think those logs have any relation?

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons behind this. Because, there is no specific error in log.
One of the solutions is this: (worked for me)

Previously, I had different package for all gcm related classes. I just put them in the same package where I was trying to do the registration. (MainActivity).